# Add JExpression (JOp.cond()) to JBlock (JMethod body)

Tags: java, sun-codemodel

I want to refactor an if - else statement into a Ternary Operator.

`if ((variable) == null) { 
    ... do something 
} else {
    ... do something else
}`

Creating a Ternary Operator with Codemodel is quite simple, as with JOp.cond() we can pass in the condition, ifTrue and ifFalse parameters to return a ternary statement.

My issue is with adding a JExpression into a method body (JBlock):

```
private void printSomeObject(final JMethod toStringMethod, FieldOutline fo) {
    String property = fo.getPropertyInfo().getName(false);
    JBlock block = toStringMethod.body();

    JExpression cond = JExpr.direct(property).eq(JExpr._null());
    JExpression ifTrue = JExpr.direct("... do something");
    JExpression ifFalse = JExpr.direct("... do something else");
    JExpression ternary = JOp.cond(cond, ifTrue, ifFalse);
    // toStringMethod.body().add(generateBody(ternary)); ONLY WORKS WITH JSTATEMENT
    ...
}
```

Has anyone an idea as to how to add a JExpression to a JBlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ternary operator is used as a statement that returns a value.  It is not a direct replacement for an if/else block.

Try compiling the following, it will fail:

```
1 == 1 ? System.out.pritln("true") : System.out.println("false");
```

JCodeModel is correct here in requiring the ternary to be a JExpression.  To add it to a JBlock you need to assign it to a variable:

```
JDefinedClass output = codeModel._class(JMod.PUBLIC, "org.Test", ClassType.CLASS);
JMethod method = output.method(JMod.PUBLIC, codeModel.VOID, "test");
method.body().decl(codeModel.ref(String.class), "value", JOp.cond(JExpr.lit(1).eq(JExpr.lit(1)), JExpr.lit("true"), JExpr.lit("false")));
```

generates:

```
public class Test {

    public void test() {
        String value = ((1 == 1)?"true":"false");
    }

}
```

Comment: if I was to use, for example, StringBuilder to generate a toString output, and needed the following statement which does not require the return value to be stored as a variable - is that possible? `stringbuilder.append(1 == 1 ? "true" : "false")`

Comment: Just found the answer - yes it is possible, by storing the JOp in an expression, and adding it to the _then block of the initial if expression - I will add this as a reply below for anyone wanting to do this in the future

Answer (score 0):

Carrying on from @John Ericksen's comment, the following code will allow you to add a ternary operator within a method call, for example, to StringBuilder.append()

```
    JExpression expr = JOp.cond(JExpr.lit(1).eq(JExpr.lit(1)), JExpr.lit("true"), JExpr.lit("false"));
    JConditional conditional = method.body()._if(JExpr.lit(x).ne(JExpr._null()));
    conditional._then().add(out.invoke("append").arg(expr1));
```

generates

```
if (x != null) { 
   out.append(((1 == 1)?"true":"false"));
}
```